# How to release NSMutableArray Saved Data in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I have an App that utilizes the [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController).  It let's my user choose up to 6 images.  I have saved those images and use them to fulfill views in other view controllers throughout the app.  However, I need to be able to release or somehow get rid of the saved data after the user comes back to the Main Menu of the app so that they can pick 6 new photos. I've just started learning NSMutableArrays and NSArrays.

Before the user comes back to the Menu I would like to clear the data on a button action.  I am using ARC, and I have had no luck searching how to release my data while utilizing ARC.  Any help would be appreciated.

**viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    for (UIView *v in [_scrollView subviews]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
    NSLog(@"info :%@", info);
    CGRect workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];

    for (int i =0; i<info.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *dict = [info objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){
            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                UIImage* image=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
                imageview.image=[images objectAtIndex:i];
                [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];
                NSString *imagePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *stringWithIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MainImage%d.jpg", i];
                NSString *imageName = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringWithIndex];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 1.0);
                BOOL result = [imageData writeToFile:imageName atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"Saved to %@? %@", imageName, (result? @"YES": @"NO"));
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;

                [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];

                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        } else if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){
            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                UIImage* image=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;

                [_scrollView addSubview:imageview];

                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uknown asset type");
        }
        self.chosenImages = images;
    }
    [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
}
```

**prank6ViewController.m**

```
@implementation Prank6ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *imagePath1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *imageName1 = [imagePath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MainImage5.jpg"];


    _prankImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName1];
}


- (IBAction)mainMenuActionBtn:(id)sender {

    /// Somehow delete all the saved images from the Array...

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainMenuSegue" sender:self];

}
@end
```

Comment: What mechanism did you use to "save those photos?"

Comment: NSString & NSData: 

 `NSString *imagePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *stringWithIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MainImage%d.jpg", i];
                NSString *imageName = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:stringWithIndex];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 1.0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was directly associated with ELCImagePickerController.  It was simply pulling way too much data at one single moment.  This would sometimes (5/10) crash the app.

Pulling 6 photos at once, my Memory Usage was at 242MB for one single view.  I decided that memory management was more important than the beautiful layout that ELCImagePickerController delivered.  So I ditched it.

And I am glad that I did.  I am doing the same exact thing but having my user choose one image at a time.  This keeps my memory usage under 12MB for the view.  All in all happy I didn't use it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

At least, UIImageJPEGRepresentation returns autoreleased NSData object I think, thus every NSData object is still on Autorelease Pool till the end of the RunLoop or wherever the end of the current Autorelease Pool scope. Use `@autoreleasepool` as the following.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageview.image, 1.0);
    BOOL result = [imageData writeToFile:imageName atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Saved to %@? %@", imageName, (result? @"YES": @"NO"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ARC will only keep objects that have strong references to them. If you no longer wish to keep something you need to drop your reference to it, usually as simple as assigning `nil` to the variable in which you are holding your reference.

Without examining your code in detail the statement:

```
self.chosenImages = nil;
```

might be what you are looking for - that will drop the reference to the mutable array and *provided* you have no other references to the array ARC will clear it up.

Also your next call to `elcImagePickerController:` creates a new array and assigns to `chosenImages`, and ARC will clean up the previous array referenced by `chosenImages` as above.

HTH

Comment: So I would just recreate the chosenImages array in my last viewcontroller by putting this `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *chosenImages;` in my .h file and then calling the code above in my IBAction?

Comment: @JoshuaHart - Maybe (not knowing your code). Or you might just put it at the start of `elcImagePickerController:` with the comment "remove last array (if any)"; or if memory isn't tight just wait until `elcImagePickerController:` assigns the new array; or...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be releasing the images.  I put it early in my ELCImagepicker, and watched my memory usage.   It stayed high and then went back thru the app and the old images were still there.  :(

Comment: @JoshuaHart - "*provided* you have no other references" - if you have a (strong) reference to an object it will be kept by ARC, if you *also* have that same object in an array dropping the array won't drop the object, you need *no* references after which ARC will clean up. If objects are staying around then you have a reference somewhere, possibly in an auto-release pool. You need to do some more detective work.